# Калькулятор на 4 арифметических действия

Tags: javascript

Я ученик 11 класса, должен создать калькулятор на 4 арифметических действия в виде:

```
текст. поле | "radio" -сложение | текст. поле | = текст. поле
            | "radio" -вычитание|
            | "radio" -умножение|
            | "radio" -деление  |
```

Почему не работает эта программа: в первое текст. поле ввожу число,во второе текст поле
ввожу число, ставлю "checked" в сложение, нажимаю на "результат", но в третьем поле ничего не появляется.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>jhgf</title>

    <body bgcolor=pink>
        <form name="form1">
            <input type=text name=text1 size=5>
            <input type=r adio name=a rifm1>додавання
            <input type=text name=text2 size=5>=
            <input type=text name=text3 size=15>
            <br>
            <font color=pink>----------</font>
            <input type=r adio name=a rifm1>віднімання
            <br>
            <font color=pink>----------</font>
            <input type=r adio name=a rifm1>множення
            <br>
            <font color=pink>----------</font>
            <input type=r adio name=a rifm1>ділення
            <br>
            <input type=button value=результат onClick="getRadioValue()">
            <!--<br><input type=button value="Вихід" `onClick= f()>-->
        </form>
    </body>
    <script language="javaScript">
        function getRadioValue() {
            var num = document.form1.elements.length;
            var a = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                var x = Number(document.form1.text1.value);
                var y = Number(document.form1.text2.value);
                if (document.form1.elements[i].type == 'radio'.checked) {
                    document.form1.text3.value = x + y;
                    a = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: @Олег2012 Уточните, что не работает.

Answer (score 1):

У вас все радиокнопки одинаковые, отличить одну от другой представляется довольно сложной задачей. Можно конечно искать по следющему за кнопкой текстовым элементом или по порядку следования, но это ненадежно, можно запутаться в итоге.

Лучше назначить id для каждой radio кнопки и проверять состояние checked каждой из них и выполнять соответствующее действие.

```
<input type="radio" name="arifm1" id="plus"><label for="plus">додавання</label>
```

и использовать его так (цикл уже не нужен!):

```
if (document.getElementById("plus").checked) {
  //здесь вычислять результат сложения
}
```

аналогично для других действий.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Калькулятор</title>
<script language="javaScript">
function getRadioValue() {
    txt1=document.getElementById("text1");
    txt2=document.getElementById("text2");
    txt3=document.getElementById("text3");
    op1=document.getElementById("op1");
    op2=document.getElementById("op1");
    op3=document.getElementById("op1");
    op4=document.getElementById("op1");
    if(op1.checked){txt3.value=(parseFloat(txt1.value)+parseFloat(txt2.value));}
    if(op2.checked){txt3.value=(parseFloat(txt1.value)-parseFloat(txt2.value));}
    if(op1.checked){txt3.value=(parseFloat(txt1.value)*parseFloat(txt2.value));}
    if(op1.checked){txt3.value=(parseFloat(txt1.value)/parseFloat(txt2.value));}
    alert(text3.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FF99FF">
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="text" id="text3">
<br>
<input type="radio" id="op1" name="res"><label for="op1">Сложение</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="op2" name="res"><label for="op2">Вычитание</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="op3" name="res"><label for="op3">Умножение</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="op4" name="res"><label for="op4">Делениние</label>
<br>
<input type="button" value="результат" onClick="getRadioValue()">
</body>
</html>
```